# Redirect nested directories to a .php

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I want to redirect legitimate directory names below a certain directory to a PHP file. I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3604160/8047) which seems to be saying that I can do something like this in the root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule /([^/]+) processDir.php?dir=$1 [B,QSA]
```

I think this is what I'm looking for, but is there a way to:

- Limit it to just directories, but allow for nested directories?
- Only filter directories: I don't want to process files.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're looking for is `RewriteCond`, which lets you conditionally apply rewrite rules. This one checks if something is a directory:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
```

You use it by putting it above your `RewriteRule`, like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule /([^/]+) processDir.php?dir=$1 [B,QSA]
```

This will work with either the method in your question or your answer, the important thing to note is that the `-d` flag checks that a request is a valid directory first before applying your rule, which is what you seemed to want.

The second part of your question, from what I gather, is about nested directories. Your regex, as it stands, is specifically looking for only one directory down (no slashes). If you want to change that, you can do something like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule /?some_dir/(.*) processDir.php?dir=$1 [B,QSA]
```

This will take any valid directory below `some_dir` and feed that into your php file.

One last thing to note is that you don't need to put all of this into you root `.htaccess` file. You can put an `.htaccess` file in the directory you want to rewrite. There's not much of a difference in doing this one way or the other, but I've found that it can simplify the syntax a bit if you're not sure what you're doing.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. +1 for now, and I'll comment back (or just accept this) once I've gotten a chance to try this all out. What does the [B, QSA] do (you can link to something too, of course)?

Comment: @Yar B is for escaping, and QSA is for query strings. Although, I just lef those alone from your post. More details at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html

Answer (score 0):

I was going to delete this question, but someone favorited it, so I'll answer it instead.

Use an .htaccess like this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ([^/]*)/$ processDir.php [B,QSA]
```

and then your processDir.php can work with this variable instead of using a get:

```
<?
dir is <?php
echo $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
?>
```

The main modification I made to the regex (that somebody will later fix) is to insist that a slash is at the end of the string.